# Mapbox searching for places displays error -TypeError: t.getCanvasContainer is not function in console

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am using a Mapbox for searching for places, while entering `city name, country` in the search area, it is throwing following error in console: `TypeError: t.getCanvasContainer is not a function at o.addTo (marker.js:226)..` Could someone please advise the reason for error here ?

//Following is my code:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([37.9, -77], 6)
    .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));

mapboxgl.accessToken = '<my-token-details>';
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
mapboxgl: mapboxgl
});

document.getElementById('geocoder').appendChild(geocoder.onAdd(map));
```

//Added the html tag:

```
<div id="geocoder" class="geocoder"></div>
```

//Pointing to following library :

```
 <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.6.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.6.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

//Error details:

Uncaught TypeError: t.getCanvasContainer is not a function
    at o.addTo (marker.js:226)
    at r._handleMarker (mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js:1)
    at r._onChange (mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js:1)
    at o.value (mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js:2)
    at r.handleMouseUp (mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js:2)

Comment: hi your code looks good ,  you use lower version try to use heigher version                          <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

Comment: Ok, Let me give a try

Comment: Not working though, I have tried with these urls `<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet'/>`

Comment: Map is loading and 4 markers are displaying which is good, but the `search input` for places gone and throws 'Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined
    at (index):394`

Comment: ok check for array of objects